Can anyone explain this error message ? C5275
I am facing a bad situation while trying to build an assembly DLL from C++ code, for .NET 7.0.
The compiler reports the messages below, even before it attempts to compile. (By the way, this should be a warning message rather than an error, due to the code number.)
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.20\ref\net7.0\mscorlib.dll(1,1): error C5275: facade assembly 'mscorlib.dll' being imported under '/clr'; missing option '/clr:netcore'?
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.20\ref\net7.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll : fatal  error C1001: Internal compiler error.

Presumably, the second error is caused by the first. The DLL uses native code wrapped in managed classes. This code works perfectly under .NET Framework (up to 4.7.2). It has a single reference, to System.Drawing.Common.dll.
Note that I am in no way including mscorlib.dll explicitly myself.
Can anyone tell me what is meant by this "facade assembly"?

Update:
I have a new hint: despite the fact that the project has the attribute clr:netcore, the individual .cpp files still have standard clr. Anyway, the IDE does not allow to specify -clr:netcore, adding it as an additional option does not work, and I have not found a syntax that works straight in the project file.

Update 2:
One can force the compilation for .NET (rather than .NET Framework) by overwriting the Common Language Runtime Support field with the text NetCore. Disregard the available options.

This is a reference assembly. It doesn’t actually contain the logic. // The project setup is unclear to me. The error message contains actionable advice: specify /clr:netcore instead of /clr. Tried that yet?

@DanielB: yes, I have set the CLR support to netcore for the project from the beginning. But I see no other place where a /clr could be applied, nor any reference to mscorlib.

@DanielB:the compiler also says "1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above." But there is no "location listed above".

Despite numerous attempts to understand and adjust parameters, I failed to make my project work.
Instead, I recreated a new class library project aimed at .NET. After reincorporating the content of my previous project, all went fine.
